# Hosting blog on different server

Tags: content-management-system, seo

We have recently launched a new website in the financial services industry. This site resides on a server that must comply to PCI rules and regulations. To generate content, I wanted to use a CMS such as blogengine.net since the application is written in asp.net but the network admins do not want a CMS on the server. So I'm wondering what the best course of action is:

1. Create a subdomain such as blog.mysite.com on a completely different server and host the blog there.
2. Scrap the blog and just create an articles or resources section, which could still reside on the same server as the application.

If I go with option 1, I'm wondering what the SEO implications are since the content would not only be on a different server but also on a subdomain.

If I go with option 2, does not having a blog hurt my SEO or is good content considered good content no matter the format.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server on which content is hosted should not matter in the eyes of Google.  Good quality, associated content is what matters.  If you have the content on a subdomain, just make sure to have a good number of links between your subdomain and the main domain, and you should be all set.

I'd encourage you to browse through Google's Webmaster Blog.  There you can find many articles detailing what Google looks for when considering how to rank websites in its search engine results.  Here's a particularly [good article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/05/more-guidance-on-building-high-quality.html), from the web spam team.